# Waiting for command to finish using SSH2_Shell in PHP

Tags: php, ssh, fwrite, libssh2

I have an SSH2_Shell session working in PHP. my issue is that i need a command to completely finish before moving onto the next command. Here is my code so far:

```
    $command_capture = "cd /mnt/NADS/scripts/";
    $command_capture2 = "./tcpdump.sh $capture_name $sleep";


    if (!($connection = ssh2_connect("172.20.1.18", 22))) {
        echo "fail: unable to establish connection";
    } 
    if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, "root", "Hideandseek")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate";
    }
    $stream = ssh2_shell($connection);

    fwrite($stream, $command_capture. PHP_EOL);
    sleep(1);
    fwrite($stream, $command_capture2 . PHP_EOL);
    sleep(5);
    $data="";
    while($buf = stream_get_contents($stream)){
        $data.=$buf;
    }
    echo $data;
    fclose($stream);
```

the tcpdump.sh script is running a lftp command but is not being given anough time to complete. I cant use sleep as it may take longer then the specified time and i dont want to make the user wait if it only needs a few seconds. I have not had luck implementing stream_set_blocking as when i do, it seems to freeze up my browser.

overall, I need a way to detect when a command has finished and move into the next command.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the ideas but I think I got it solved. I did an echo of a few special characters when the command finished and then I would search for the characters using strpos(). Another thing I think may have helped was adjusting the max_execution_time setting in the php.ini file. I found that answer here:

http://verysimple.com/2006/03/30/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded/

And here is my new code

```
    $data="";
    while (true){
        $data .= stream_get_contents($stream);
        if (strpos($data,"XOXO") !== false) {
            echo "okay: command finished\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    echo $data;
    fclose($stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an SSH2 class that implements the Secure Shell2 over on github .. check out https://github.com/bubba-h57/PHP-SSH2 and see if that helps.

I continue to search for a better way to handle finding the prompts though, so any advice or contribution to that would be welcomed. Hopefully it will help, if nothing more than giving you some ideas.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2();
$ssh->login('username', 'password');

echo $ssh->exec('command');
echo $ssh->exec('command2');
?>
```

If you really need shell support you could do the following (with the latest SVN):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2();
$ssh->login('username', 'password');

$ssh->read('[prompt]');
$ssh->write("command\n");
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
$ssh->write("command\n");
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```