# different time delaying to download files

Tags: php

I have a php function, which sends a linux command to zip a number of selected files. The file is then downloaded.

```
$command = "zip data ";

foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key=>$llogfile){     
    $command = $command . $llogfile . ' ';
}

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true); 
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);

//sleep(1);

$file = 'data.zip';
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$filetype = finfo_file($finfo, $file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Type: '.$filetype);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. basename($file));
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

If `sleep()` is disabled, the .zip file is downloaded with no files. I think it might be because of the processing time to zip files at the server.

My isse is the following: Since the user chooses the amount of files to be zipped, zipping time may vary, therefore, `sleep(999)` doesn't seem a good solution and `sleep(1)` might not work properly when large amount of files are chosen.

Is there any easier way to wait for the command to be executed before downloading the file?

**Important:** 
**I cannot zip files on php side, it has to be done this way. Security is not important since this is being used for personal purposes.**

Comment: PHP has some standard libraries to perform zipping itself, this ensures that the command is processed before downloading.

Comment: Thanks captain. But I have to do it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, can't comment yet but:

[Waiting for command to finish using SSH2_Shell in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724277/waiting-for-command-to-finish-using-ssh2-shell-in-php)

so you can do the same:

```
 while (true){
        $data .= stream_get_contents($stream);
        if (strpos($data,"XOXO") !== false) {
            echo "okay: command finished\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    echo $data;
    fclose($stream);
```

just replace "XOXO" with something that zip command return to the stream

hope it is helpful